# Shopify - How solve - Uncaught ReferenceError: theme is not defined -

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, shopify

I'm trying to add Shopify's "Shipping Estimator" to the Cart page and followed their instructions here:
https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Add-a-shipping-rates-calculator-to-your-cart/td-p/616554.
I'm using the "Supply" theme - so followed their 'Sectioned' instructions.

But I get the error "Uncaught Reference Error; theme is not defined"

Where should I start looking for where "theme" is suppose to be defined?

```
<script>     
  theme.strings = {
      shippingCalcSubmitButton: "Calculate shipping",
      shippingCalcSubmitButtonDisabled: "Calculating...",
      
      shippingCalcMoneyFormat: "\u003cspan class=money\u003e\u003cspan class=money\u003e\u0026pound;{{amount}} GBP\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e"
  }
</script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="/services/javascripts/countries.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/shopify/assets/themes_support/shopify_common-8ea6ac3faf357236a97f5de749df4da6e8436ca107bc3a4ee805cbf08bc47392.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the {{theme}} liquid object?  I'm not entirely sure if you can write to those in that way.  https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/theme

If you want to read from the {{theme}} object, you might be able to do `console.log({{theme | json}}.strings.shippingCalcSubmitButton)`.  The {{theme | json}} gets executed on Shopify's servers and will be replaced with a big JSON object at the time your JS runs.  But modifying it from JS won't affect other spots where {{theme}} is accessed since liquid is executed server-side.

Comment: In answer to your Q:  I don't know.   I was just following orders (well instructions) I didn't know there was a {{theme}} object, but now on looking at documentation, it only contains Name of the theme etc.  So I don't think it's that

Comment: you need to add the `var theme = window.theme || {};` begging of the your JS code.

Comment: Well adding that - removed the error msg., but the code isn't working ;(

Comment: Are you sure all the code suggested on-page is copied and paste properly?

Comment: I've checked twice ... but your absolutely right ... I'll check slowly again.

Comment: I checked and it was OK then @ArtHare 's post gave me the clue because I found {{theme}} elsewhere in the code working OK.  So thinking sequence was the issue, I moved the relevant <scripts> into the <head> ... and no longer get the error.  Unfortunately ... I now hit another issues ... which I've raised in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186518/script-type-text-template-not-being-recognised-correctly-in-shopify-store

Answer (score 0):

add to the theme.liquid this part inside head tags

```
  <script>
    var theme = window.theme || {};
  </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCdvn.png)

this is solution for DAWN THEME

for other steps follow this links
https://www.huratips.com/tech-tips/add-a-shipping-rates-calculator-to-your-shopify-cart.html