# How to translate an Underscore template to a Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, shopify, underscore.js

I'm upgrading a Shopify store that's using an old theme.

In the (old) Cart page is code for a 'Shipping Estimator' which (because it works well) they want to re-use in the new theme.
I've copied across the relevant files but on execution and pressing the Calculate button, we get the following displayed:

> class="success" <% } else { %> class="error" <% } %>> <% if (success)
> { %> <% if (rates.length > 1) { %> There are <%= rates.length %>
> shipping rates available for <%= address %>, starting at <%=
> rates[0].price %>. <% } else if (rates.length == 1) { %> ....

This comes from the following code:

```
<script id="shipping-calculator-response-template" type="text/template">
  <p id="shipping-rates-feedback" <% if (success) { %> class="success" <% } else { %> class="error" <% } %>>
  <% if (success) { %>
    <% if (rates.length > 1) { %> 
    There are <%= rates.length %> shipping rates available for <%= address %>, starting at <%= rates[0].price %>.
    <% } else if (rates.length == 1) { %>
    ... 
</script>
```

So, I guess the script is not being recognise/treated as  'text/template'

The new theme includes a reference to:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

And the old theme:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I commented out **handlebar**, and replaced with **underscore**. But still the same result.

Am I on the right track, or is the above irrelevant?

The full code that I need to decipher from Underscore - and re-code for HandleBars is as follows:

```
<script id="shipping-calculator-response-template" type="text/template">
  <p id="shipping-rates-feedback" <% if (success) { %> class="success" <% } else { %> class="error" <% } %>>
  <% if (success) { %>
    <% if (rates.length > 1) { %> 
    There are <%- rates.length %> shipping rates available for <%- address %>, starting at <%= rates[0].price %>.
    <% } else if (rates.length == 1) { %>
    There is one shipping rate available for <%- address %>.
    <% } else { %>
    We do not ship to this destination.
    <% } %>
  <% } else { %>
    <%- errorFeedback %>
  <% } %>
  </p>
  <ul id="shipping-rates">
    <% for (var i=0; i<rates.length; i++) { %>
    <li><%- rates[i].name %> at <%= rates[i].price %></li>
    <% } %>
  </ul> 
</script>
```

If we can get this to work, there are a lot of shopify merchants that will be very happy ;)

Comment: yes, you are on the right track to use underscore.js  however, suggestion to remove that since it is kind of obsolete.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesC. with your info.   I did all the changes again -carefully! and commented out 'Handlesbars.js' and added a link to 'underscore.js' and the code then worked fine.  Unfortunately, other bits of code stopped working correctly ;((.    Is there a way I can direct some script code to use Underscore and others(most) to use Handlebars?    Or is there a way to 'convert' Underscore' script to be 'Handlebars' compliant?  [without me having to learn all about templating - which is way above my pay-grade/competence;) ]

Comment: handlebar and underscore can be together. There is no direct script translation afaik. Since you are using the handlebar theme, recommend to change all from underscore (minor portion) to handlebar.  Handlebar is not hard and is extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand. If they can be together - how? Or, I'm happy to change from Underscore to Handlebars throughout - but how?    If I give the complete Underscore script, can someone convert this into HandleBar compatible for me.  I've read documents on Underscore -v- Handlebars ... but don't understand what I'm reading ;(

Comment: In searching - I've found<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div>
      My name is {{name}}. I am a {{occupation}}.
   </div>
</script>    If this directs it to handlebars, is there something that directs to Underscore?

Comment: let update the questions to include the code you want to convert (a more complete version)

Comment: Charles C, I disagree that Underscore is obsolete. Although the JavaScript standard has ported some of its functions, most Underscore functions are still not in the standard. Moreover, those few functions that entered the standard are much less powerful than their Underscore counterparts. For example, Underscore can do `_.map({a: [1], b: [2, 3], c: [4, 5, 6]}, 'length')` giving you `[1, 2, 3]`. Doing that with vanilla JS is going to require a lot more code.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesC. I've added the complete script to the end of the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org) and [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com) are not really alternatives to each other. Underscore is a toolkit with general functional utilities, which helps you write shorter, more maintainable code in functional style. Handlebars, on the other hand, is a library entirely dedicated to template rendering, which helps you write cleaner, more maintainable templates.

When using Underscore, you may find its functions being called everywhere throughout your JavaScript code, while Handlebars is only called in places where you'll be rendering a template. For this reason, these libraries normally don't conflict at all; it is perfectly possible to write an application that depends on both (in fact I've been doing this for a while in most of my applications). Just link both libraries into your page,

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.12.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@4.7.7/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
```

or import both as modules,

```js
import _ from 'underscore';
import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars';
```

or do the same with an older module format such as AMD or CommonJS.

However, Underscore does have a [`template`](https://underscorejs.org/#template) function, which is a very minimal templating implementation that can be used as an alternative to a library like Handlebars. This appears to be the case in the old version of your application, and it is causing conflicts because Underscore's minimal templating language is different from Handlebars's templating language. The compilation and rendering steps are also a bit different between these libraries.

### Comparing the template languages

Both template languages let you insert special tags in a piece of text in order to make parts of that text parametric, conditional or repetitive. The tags that they support are however different.

Underscore:

- `<%= expression %>` will insert the string value of the JavaScript `expression` in the text. This is called an interpolation tag.
- `<%- expression %>` will do the same, but HTML-escaped.
- `<% code %>` lets you write arbitrary JavaScript `code` that will make parts of the template conditional or repetitive. Often, you'll find that one such tag goes something like `<% for (...) { %>` and then a bit further down the template, there is a matching `<% } %>`. The part of the template between those two code tags is then a loop that will repeat by the logic of the `for`. Similarly, you may find `<% if (...) { %>...<% } %>` to make the `...` part of the template conditional. (Honestly, this is quite ugly, but it helps the implementation to be minimal. Underscore's [template module](https://underscorejs.org/docs/modules/template.html) is only one page.)
- Inside the `code` part of `<% code %>` you may occasionally find `print(expression)`. This is a shorthand meant to avoid having to break out of the code tag, insert an interpolation tag with `expression` and then immediately resume with a new code tag. In other words, `<% code1 print(expression) code2 %>` is a shorthand for `<% code1 %><%= expression %><% code2 %>`.

Handlebars:

- `{{name}}` inserts the HTML-escaped string value of the property with key `name` in the template.
- `{{{name}}}` does the same, but *without* HTML-escaping.
- `{{#if condition}}...{{/if}}` will insert the `...` part only if `condition` is met.
- `{{#each name}}...{{/each}}` will repeat `...` for each element or property of `name`. `name` becomes the *context* of the `...`; that is, if you write `{{otherName}}` within `...`, Handlebars will try to find `otherName` as a property of the object identified by `name`.
- `{{#name}}...{{/name}}` is a notation that Handlebars inherits from [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io). It behaves similar to `{{#each name}}` when `name` is an array and similar to `{{#if name}}` otherwise (also changing the context to `name` if it is an object). The idea behind this (in Mustache) is to make the template even more declarative, or "logic-free" as the authors call it.
- There are more tags that I won't go into now.

### Translating Underscore templates to Handlebars

Since Underscore allows the insertion of arbitrary JavaScript code in a template, it is not always possible to translate an Underscore template to an equivalent Handlebars template. Fortunately, however, templates don't really need the full expressive power of JavaScript, so Underscore templates are likely to be written in a way that *can* be ported to a more restrictive template language ("lucky by accident"). When it is possible, the following strategy will be sufficient most of the time:

1. Replace any occurrences of `print(_.escape(expression))` that appear inside any `<%...%>` tag by `%><%- expression %><%`.
2. Replace any other occurrences of `print(expression)` inside `<%...%>` by `%><%= expression %><%`.
3. Replace all occurrences of `<%- expression %>` (including ones that were already there before step 1) by `{{expression}}`.
4. Replace all occurrences of `<%= expression %>` (including ones that were already there before step 2) by `{{{expression}}}`.
5. If you find aliases of the form `var name = otherName.propertyName` anywhere (**except** within the parentheses of a `for (...)` statement), substitute `otherName.propertyName` for `name` everwhere this variable is in scope and drop the variable. **Don't** do this with loop variables inside `for (...)`; those are replaced in step 7.
6. If you find any pattern of the form `<% if (condition1) { %>...<% } else if (condition2) { %>...<% } else ... if (conditionN) { %>...<% } else { %>...<% } %>`, start with the last, innermost block and work your way outwards from there, as follows:

   - Replace the final `<% } else { %>` by `{{else}}` (Handlebars recognizes this as a special notiation).
   - Replace the final intermediate `<% } else if (conditionN) { %>...<% } %>` by `{{else}}{{#if conditionN }}...{{/if}}<% } %>`. Repeat this step until there is no more `else if`. Note that the final `<% } %>` **stays in place**; you're inserting one additional `{{/if}}` in front of it for every intermediate `else if`.
   - Replace the outermost `<% if (condition1) { %>...<% } %>` by `{{#if condition1}}...{{/if}}`. This time, the final `<% } %>` disappears.
7. Replace loops, again starting with the innermost expressions and working your way outwards from there:

   - Replace **functional loops over objects** of the form `<% _.each(objectName, function(valueName, keyName, collectionName) { %>...<% }) %>` by the notation `{{#each objectName}}...{{/each}}`. Check nested `{{}}`/`{{{}}}`/`{{#if}}`/`{{#each}}` tags within `...` for any appearances of `keyName`, `collectionName` or `objectName` and replace them by by `@key`, `..` and `..` respectively (that is not a typo; `collectionName` and `objectName` should both be replaced by `..` because they refer to the same object). Note that the function passed to `_.each` in the Underscore version may take fewer arguments, in which case `collectionName` and even `keyName` may be absent; the replacement works the same regardless.
   - Replace **functional loops over arrays** of the form `<% _.each(arrayName, function(valueName, indexName, collectionName) { %>...<% }) %>` by the notation `{{#each arrayName}}...{{/each}}`. Check nested `{{}}`/`{{{}}}`/`{{#if}}`/`{{#each}}` tags within `...` for any appearances of `indexName`, `collectionName` or `arrayName` and replace them by by `@index`, `..` and `..` respectively. Again, the function passed to `_.each` in the Underscore version may take fewer arguments; the replacement works the same regardless.
   - Replace **procedural loops over objects** of the form `<% for (var keyName in objectName) { %>...<% } %>` by the notation `{{#each objectName}}...{{/each}}`. Check nested `{{}}`/`{{{}}}`/`{{#if}}`/`{{#each}}` tags within `...` for any appearances of `keyName`, `objectName[keyName]` or `objectName` and replace them by by `@key`, `this` and `..` respectively.
   - Replace **procedural loops over arrays** of the form `<% for (var indexName = 0; indexName < arrayName.length; ++indexName) { %>...<% } %>` by the notation `{{#each arrayName}}...{{/each}}`. Check nested `{{}}`/`{{{}}}`/`{{#if}}`/`{{#each}}` tags within `...` for any appearances of `indexName`, `arrayName[indexName]` or `arrayName` and replace them by by `@index`, `this` and `..` respectively.
8. Fix expression syntax:

   - If you have created expressions of the form `...propertyName` in the previous step, where the first two periods `..` were originally a name (`objectName` or `arrayName` as described under step 7), replace this by `../propertyName`. You may have longer paths of this form, for example `../../propertyName`.
   - Subexpressions of the form `name[index1][index2]` should be turned into `name.[index].[index2]` (note the periods).
9. Check whether all `expression`s and `condition`s that you translated can be evaluated as-is by Handlebars. As a rule of thumb, Handlebars can only directly evaluate (nested) property names of the current context (for example `keyName` or `keyName.subProperty`) and some special notations that it recognizes such as `@key`, `@index`, `@root`, `this` and `..`. Use [helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#sub-expressions) to evaluate expressions that are more than just the name of some object and anchor names as necessary to `@root` or `..`:

   - Note that `this.propertyName` is equivalent to just `propertyName`, because `this` refers to the current context.
   - When passing an object like `{a: foo, b: {c: baz}}` to the template, the properties of this outermost object can always be referenced with `@root.a`, `@root.b.c`, etcetera. Note that this object may have been given a name of its own inside the original Underscore template; in that case, this name itself can be replaced by `@root`.
   - `..` is for referencing the parent context inside loops, as we have seen in steps 7-8. Occasionally, a loop in the original Underscore template may reference a property of a parent context directly by closing over it; in such cases, you can help Handlebars find the right property by prefixing the name of this property with `../` as necessary.
10. You may have leftover empty `<% %>` tags after the previous transformations; these can be safely removed.

If, after the above steps, you still have `<% code %>` notation in your template, or expressions that Handlebars cannot evaluate, you may need to use other facilities from the Handlebars language or create special workarounds. If you are very unlucky, the template cannot be translated at all, but most of the time there will be a way.

### Demonstration: your template

Repeating the Underscore template from your question here:

```html
<p id="shipping-rates-feedback" <% if (success) { %> class="success" <% } else { %> class="error" <% } %>>
<% if (success) { %>
  <% if (rates.length > 1) { %>
  There are <%- rates.length %> shipping rates available for <%- address %>, starting at <%= rates[0].price %>.
  <% } else if (rates.length == 1) { %>
  There is one shipping rate available for <%- address %>.
  <% } else { %>
  We do not ship to this destination.
  <% } %>
<% } else { %>
  <%- errorFeedback %>
<% } %>
</p>
<ul id="shipping-rates">
  <% for (var i=0; i<rates.length; i++) { %>
  <li><%- rates[i].name %> at <%= rates[i].price %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Following the above algorithm and using the expression `rates.[1]` instead of `rates.length > 1` (because Handlebars cannot evaluate comparisons out of the box), we successfully obtain the following Handlebars template:

```html
<p id="shipping-rates-feedback" {{#if success}} class="success" {{else}} class="error" {{/if}}>
{{#if success}}
  {{#if rates.[1]}}
  There are {{rates.length}} shipping rates available for {{address}}, starting at {{{rates.[0].price}}}.
  {{else}}{{#if rates}}
  There is one shipping rate available for {{address}}.
  {{else}}
  We do not ship to this destination.
  {{/if}}{{/if}}
{{else}}
  {{errorFeedback}}
{{/if}}
</p>
<ul id="shipping-rates">
  {{#each rates}}
  <li>{{name}} at {{{price}}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

You might find other templates that need to be translated as well. You can follow the same approach for those other templates.

### Final note: templates embedded in HTML

Your theme includes the template in the page with the following notation.

```html
<script id="shipping-calculator-response-template" type="text/template">
    // the template
</script>
```

It is important to realize that, although this is a `<script>` tag, the browser does not actually interpret the contents as a script. Instead, because the tag has a `type` that the browser doesn't know, the browser just leaves the tag as-is in the DOM and moves on to interpret the next element. This is a common trick to embed arbitrary text data in an HTML page, so that it can be picked up by a script later without the user having to see it. In this particular case, there will be a piece of your JavaScript somewhere that will do something like

```js
var templateText = document.querySelector('#shipping-calculator-response-template').textContent;
```

and then pass `templateText` to Handlebars in order to process it. This is also the reason why replacing Handlebars back by Underscore didn't solve your problem; that script will still try to pass the template to Handlebars. Concluding, in your particular case, there is probably no need to put back the Underscore reference.

Comment: I replaced the old t'plate script with the new one, and replace the reference to underscore with the ref to handlebars.  On execution no text is displayed, but I get a console msg: Uncaught TypeError: _.template is not a function
    at _render (jquery.cart.min.js?v=10050315836398378908:11).  I guess jquery.cart.min.js need modifying as well, or is there a mistake in my replacements?  Should I add the full transcript of jquery.cart.min.js to the Q?

Comment: I tried changing jquery.cart.min.js to a version from a newer theme.  On execution it displays:  "There are shipping rates available for , starting at }. There is one shipping rate available for . We do not ship to this destination.

at }"     Without console errors.

Comment: That sounds like the names of the properties in de data that are passed to Handlebars have changed. Your best bet is to find the piece of code that calls Handlebars in order to render the template and set a breakpoint in order to find out what's going on.

Comment: Although, at second thought, it is surprising that all three branches of the if/else if/else are being rendered. Hard to tell what's going on without seeing the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228968/discussion-between-julian-and-user801347).